# How to Install ffmpeg on aws lambda machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a node js script on AWS lambda that uses ffmpeg. To do this, I need to install ffmpeg on the machine itself.

I have looked through the documentation but I could not find how to connect to the machine that runs the lambda.

Comment: You can't. If you want ffmpeg then you either have to upload it with your zipped up code, or download it at runtime to the local filesystem of the Lambda container. If it's in the root of your ZIP file then I believe that it is installed at /var/task, but it will not have +x permissions so you'll need to add those in your Lambda code. Running ffmpeg in Lambda is moderately painful. There are various Github projects that try to make using fffmpeg in Lambda simpler (e.g. fluent-ffmpeg) but none solves the issue of building an ffmpeg binary and getting it installed with the correct permissions.

Comment: [I have answered here step by step on how to include ffmpeg in your lambda instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788269/7441059) Don't forget to leave a thumbs up mate :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't ever connect to the "machine" the Lambda is running on. There is no single machine the function runs on, and the function isn't even deployed until the first time it is called. The Lambda runs in one or more containers that are created and deleted on demand as requests come in. You have to include anything like ffmpeg in your Lambda's deployment package itself, so it will be there every time your function is deployed to a container.

Any binaries you include in your function's deployment package need to be built for Amazon Linux, which is the operating system Lambda runs on. You can either [use an EC2 server to build the binaries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) or search for someone that has already packaged ffmpeg for Lambda and made it available.

Answer (score 21):

To use ffmpeg as quickly as possible in AWS Lambda, simply use the pre-built lambda layer which can be found at: [https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~ffmpeg-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Effmpeg-lambda-layer)

Just deploy this layer and then attach is to your function.
To invoke ffmpeg, just use '/opt/bin/ffmpeg' path in your lambda function.

The layer is maintained in a Git:
https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer

Answer (score 20):

This works for me in Python:

1. Get static build of ffmpeg [from here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), as already mentioned by @Xeroxoid
2. Untar with `tar -zxvf ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz`
3. Fetch file `ffmpeg` (and optionally `ffprobe`) from folder.
4. Put bare ffmpeg file (without the subfolder) in the same folder as your lambda code.
5. `cd` into this folder and zip with `zip -r -X "../archive.zip" *`
6. Upload zipped file to AWS Lambda.

Set the correct filepath to ffmpeg like so:

```
FFMPEG_STATIC = "/var/task/ffmpeg"
import subprocess
subprocess.call([FFMPEG_STATIC, '-i', input_file, output_file])
```

Comment: Worked for us thanks!  Just needed to do ./ffmpeg for the path

Comment: How come this isn't the upvoted and correct answer. Works like a charm. There's also more info here: https://medium.com/dev-genius/how-to-process-media-in-aws-lambda-ffmpeg-f53491cf8768

Comment: do you git add ffmpeg and ffprobe as well? git warns that they are large files

Comment: @Jun I do not use git in the mentioned workflow. But yes, both files are somewhat bigger, ffmpeg having around 80 MB. So warnings from git can be expected. However, you don´t need to use git to make ffmpeg available for your AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 8):

You can also find pre-compiled versions of `ffmpeg` for `aws-lambda` hosted by this cool dude, here: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

(I went with the `x86_64` build)

Tip: don't forget to set the correct `+x` permissions for the binaries `ffmpeg` and perhaps `ffprobe` if needed.

Comment: How do you add the directory where the executable is added within the bundle to the path? I have a lambda that includes ffmpeg as per the link above, but a call to `which ffmpeg` returns null (meaning it's not finding my executable).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use ffmpeg in my lambda function, but when I included it as a Lambda Layer, or included it in the source package, I went over the allowed max size for the lambda function.

Using docker with lambda would probably be a good way to work around the size limitation, but my workflow would need to be refactored, so, I decided to make a workaround by zipping the static [amd64 ffmpeg binary](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and dropping it in a bucket that my lambda function can access.

This function will grab the zip from S3 and unzip it into the Lambda `/tmp` directory where it can be called via `subprocess.check_output()`.

> I zipped the `ffmpeg` binary in `bin/ffmpeg` for the package.
> You really don't need to zip it, and could just place the binary in S3.  Lambda (/tmp) can be configured to have storage between 512 MB and 10,240 MB.

```py
import logging
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from zipfile import ZipFile

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from zappa.asynchronous import task

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

S3_CLIENT = boto3.client("s3")


def prepare_ffmpeg(bucket: str, key: str) -> Path:
    ffmpeg_binary_path = Path("/tmp/ffmpeg")
    with BytesIO() as bytesbuffer:
        logger.info(f"Downloading package s3://{bucket}/{key} ...")
        try:
            S3_CLIENT.download_fileobj(bucket, key, bytesbuffer)
        except ClientError as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            logger.error(f"Downloading package s3://{bucket}/{key} ... ERROR")
        else:
            logger.info(f"Downloading package s3://{bucket}/{key} ... COMPLETE")
            logger.info(f"Unzipping 'bin/ffmpeg' from {key} to {ffmpeg_binary_path} ...")
            bytesbuffer.seek(0)
            z = ZipFile(bytesbuffer)
            with ffmpeg_binary_path.open("wb") as fileout:
                ffmpeg_content = z.read("bin/ffmpeg")
                fileout.write(ffmpeg_content)
            ffmpeg_binary_path.chmod(0o777)
            logger.info(f"Unzipping 'bin/ffmpeg' from {key} to {ffmpeg_binary_path} ... COMPLETE")
            assert ffmpeg_binary_path.exists()
    return ffmpeg_binary_path
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement where I needed to use FFmpeg to generate videos in an AWS Lambda function. Since my application had some bulk due to `node_modules` and other files, I chose to use AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) to create a Docker image and use it as a base image for Lambda.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. First, I downloaded the FFmpeg binary in zip format from [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).
2. After downloading, I unzipped the zip file, which gave me an extracted folder with the FFmpeg binary inside it.
3. Next, I copied the FFmpeg binary from the extracted folder to the root of my project at the Dockerfile level.
4. Then, I modified my Dockerfile to copy the FFmpeg binary to the `/usr/bin` folder. Here's what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs

# ENV DEBUG="puppeteer:*"

# Copy the FFmpeg binary to /usr/bin
COPY ffmpeg /usr/bin

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of your application code
COPY index.js ./
COPY *.service.js ./

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "index.handler" ]
```

By following these steps and including the FFmpeg binary in the Docker image, you can use FFmpeg in your AWS Lambda function without any issues.