# Lambda not connecting to ffmpeg

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have an issue with a Lambda function that tries to use ffmpeg as a third party on AWS. The function itself uses ffmpeg.js library which generates ffmpeg commands in it's functions, when they are called. I installed ffmpeg on my instance via SSH, and it's still giving me the same error

> Command failed: ffmpeg -i "....
>    ffmpeg: command not found

Any advice on this? Many thanks

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg

Comment: @Katerina, what did you end up using? Thanks

Comment: @Jun Hello. The issue was with the permissions. I end up creating the zip file containing the ffmpeg exe directly on the AWS. The issue was with when I zipped the file locally and then uploading it on AWS.

Comment: @Katerina I see. have to `chmod +x`

Answer (score 9):

You need to include static build of ffmpeg inside your project directory

[Download x86_64 version. As it the one used my lambda environment](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)

Unzip the file and copy ffmpeg named file which is binary build and paste it in your project directory.

After that on the top of your code paste the following snippet:

```
process.env.PATH = process.env.PATH + ':/tmp/'
process.env['FFMPEG_PATH'] = '/tmp/ffmpeg';
const BIN_PATH = process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] 
rocess.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + BIN_PATH;
```

Now inside your exports.handler, paste the following line of code in the beginning of function call. It will look like this

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
require('child_process').exec(
'cp /var/task/ffmpeg /tmp/.; chmod 755 /tmp/ffmpeg;',
function (error, stdout, stderr) {
if (error) {
console.log('Erro occured',error);
} else {
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
// Your task to be performed
}
}
)
}
```

I hope this helps. Don't forget to leave a thumbs up :) 
Above solution is for Node.js language

Comment: would you be able to help me implement this in Python?

Comment: @alaysd, can u give an example of ffmpeg code? thanks
I am using Python and have the file in local environment in lambda but I can't get it run using subprocess.

Comment: @alaysd, when I ran this command using Python, I got this error `Read-only file system` Did u get a similar error?

Comment: @charsi Yes, I successfully can use ffmpeg with Python. See my answer in thread.

Comment: @alaysd i tried you solution, the ffmpeg static build does not go with serverless deploy, i tried checking in lambda detail, it is not there, do we need to change any setting to send StaticBuild(ffmpeg) with lambda.. please help.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully can work with ffmpeg on AWS Lambda in Python:

1. Get static build of ffmpeg [from here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).
2. Untar with `tar -zxvf ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz`
3. Fetch file `ffmpeg` (and optionally `ffprobe`) from folder and delete rest of files.
4. Put bare ffmpeg file (without the subfolder) in the same folder as your lambda code.
5. `cd` into this folder and zip with `zip -r -X "../archive.zip" *`
6. Upload zipped file to AWS Lambda and save.

In your Python code you need to set the correct filepath to the ffmpeg static build like so:

```
FFMPEG_STATIC = "/var/task/ffmpeg"
# now call ffmpeg with subprocess
import subprocess
subprocess.call([FFMPEG_STATIC, '-i', input_file, output_file])
```

I didn´t have to change any file permissions. This wouldn't have worked anyways because `/var/task/` doesn't seem to be writeable.

`input_file` and `output_file` are local files in your spawned Lambda instance. I download my files from s3 to `/tmp/` and do the processing with ffmpeg there. Make also sure to set sufficient memory and timeout for the Lambda (I use maximum settings for my workflow).

Comment: @ChetanVashisth I just checked again – it still works perfectly fine. Why do you assume that it doesn't?

Comment: I have zip file which contains ffmpeg and ffprobe but when i try to print the path as /opt/python/ffmpeg it did not work . Note my lambda function is not in the zip and  i am using layers not deployment package

Comment: @ChetanVashisth That's a different scenario that I haven't tried and that wasn't asked by OP. Can I suggest that you post this as a new question?