# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, alexa-skills-kit, ffprobe

I have to develop an Alexa Skill that use Pydub for edit mp3 file.

Pydub requires ffmpeg and so I have add it in requirements.txt but now, when I try to run my skill, it give me *"Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."*.

In CloudWatch the error is: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'` but in requirements.txt there is the ffprobe import.

NB: In local the code runs successfully without any errors

Screenshot:
[Error in CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MysR2.jpg)

Comment: `No such file or directory` is not an import error; it sounds like it's trying to do a regular `open()` on that filename.

Comment: Can also get that from an attempt to start an executable, if no program by that name exists. Which sounds like the problem here -- importing a `ffprobe` Python module won't install a `ffprobe` executable; the Python module is just a wrapper, you need to have the executable separately installed for it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Install ffmpeg on aws lambda machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044448/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-aws-lambda-machine)

Answer (score 0):

I had once a problem with ffprobe (`No such file or directory`), but when recording an animation using matplotlib. I solved it just by installing ffprobe and adding it to "path" in environment variables (on Windows). Maybe it could work for you.