# Issue with running ffmpeg command using python in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

My use case is to concatenate the files using ffmpeg. I do it by specifying the S3 URLs (in a text file /tmp/files.txt) of the files to be concatenated.

Below is the command and and the way I run it using Python:

```
ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i /tmp/files.txt -c copy /tmp/output.mp4"
subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The same Python file works perfectly fine when I run it on my Windows machine. But when it is run on AWS Lambda function, it fails. Please find below the error I get:

> "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -f
> concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i
> /tmp/files.txt -c copy /tmp/output.mp4'",   "errorType":
> "FileNotFoundError"

Am I doing it the right way? I suppose yes, as it works just fine on my Windows PC.

If someone faced this issue and fixed it, please help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to first make sure that `/tmp/files.txt` exists on the local Lambda file system.

Comment: It does exist. I create the pre-signed S3 URLs and update the files.txt file with these URLs. I print the content to ensure that the file exists and has the required data.

Comment: And as I mentioned in the question also, the same script works just fine when it is run on a Windows machine.

Comment: How did you deploy ffmpeg into the Lambda runtime environment?

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG is not pre-installed in the Lambda runtime environment. It has to be explicitly deployed as a Lambda Layer or bundled and uploaded with your Lambda function. If you *did* deploy it then the `ffmpeg` binary may not be executable or may not be on your PATH.

Here are a few options for deploying FFMPEG:

1. [ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer](https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer)
2. [ffmpeg-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/ffmpeg-lambda-layer)
3. [install FFMPEG on Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044448/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-aws-lambda-machine)

I tested a simple Lambda Python function *without* FFMPEG binaries and saw exactly the error message you are seeing. This is evidence that the `ffmpeg` binary is not installed in your Lambda environment or not on your PATH. The actual location of an uploaded `ffmpeg` binary depends on where you upload it to but it would typically be under `/var/task/` if you uploaded the binary as part of your Lambda Layer or under `/opt/` if deployed as part of your Lambda package. Rather than simply trying to execute `ffmpeg`, you might want to list files in those locations to verify what you have deployed.

Comment: Yes, knowing this, I have already added a layer for ffmpeg dependency. I have another Lambda function for creating video clips. In that Lambda function, I am already running the ffmpeg command and creating video clips. For some strange reasons, I am not able to run this ffmpeg command in this Lambda function.

Comment: Assuming that it is the ffmpeg which is not found, I tried with: "ffmpeg", "/opt/ffmpeg", "./ffmpeg", etc. but none of these helped.

Comment: Added updated text about location of deployed files. You'll need to verify the mechanism you're using to upload ffmpeg and then check the relevant folders, and also check the +x execute permission on ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/ffmpeglib/ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i /tmp/audio_list.txt -c copy /tmp/output.mp4"

command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)

p1 = subprocess.run(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```